# What is wrong with sending signal after fork in below code

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork, kill

i wrote the below code: after fork() function the parent send a signal to child. i think the child receive the signal and terminates.
i don't want the solution because i can solve it by two below ways.
i want to know what is the cause of this problem?

what i tried at first is below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define maxchild 1

int inchild=-1;

void sighandler(int signo){
    char buffer[256];
    int a,b=0;
    switch(signo){
    case SIGUSR1:
        printf("SIGUSR1\n");
        break;
    case SIGUSR2:
        printf("SIGUSR2\n");
        break;
}
}


int main(){
pid_t ids[maxchild];
struct sigaction control;
control.sa_flags=0;
control.sa_handler=sighandler;
sigemptyset(&control.sa_mask);
sigaction(SIGUSR1,&control,NULL);
sigaction(SIGUSR2,&control,NULL);
for(int i=0;i<maxchild;i++){
    ids[i]=fork();
    printf("here %d\n",ids[i]);
    if(ids[i]==0){
        printf("in child\n");
        inchild=i+1;
        break;
    }
}
while(inchild>=0) {
}
//  sleep(1);
if(inchild==-1){
    for(int i=0;i<maxchild;i++){
        printf("child: %d\n parent: %d\n",ids[i],getpid());
        kill(ids[i],SIGUSR1);
    }

}
  if (inchild==-1) wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

when i run the code so many times, i expect to see the "SIGUSR1" in output every time but mostly the output is:

```
here 17573 (or any other positive number)
child: 17573
parent: 17572
```

and then program terminates suddenly.
i understand i can solve it by two solution:
1. parent most sleep after fork() function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define maxchild 1

int inchild=-1;

void sighandler(int signo){
    char buffer[256];
    int a,b=0;
    switch(signo){
    case SIGUSR1:
        printf("SIGUSR1\n");
        break;
    case SIGUSR2:
        printf("SIGUSR2\n");
        break;
}
}


int main(){
pid_t ids[maxchild];
struct sigaction control;
control.sa_flags=0;
control.sa_handler=sighandler;
sigemptyset(&control.sa_mask);
sigaction(SIGUSR1,&control,NULL);
sigaction(SIGUSR2,&control,NULL);
for(int i=0;i<maxchild;i++){
    ids[i]=fork();
    printf("here %d\n",ids[i]);
    if(ids[i]==0){
        printf("in child\n");
        inchild=i+1;
        break;
    }
}
while(inchild>=0) {
}
    sleep(1);
if(inchild==-1){
    for(int i=0;i<maxchild;i++){
        printf("child: %d\n parent: %d\n",ids[i],getpid());
        kill(ids[i],SIGUSR1);
    }

}
  if (inchild==-1) wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

that it will work fine

2. i can comment the "kill(...)" line too to solve the problem:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/wait.h>
   #include <sys/time.h>
   #include <wait.h>
   #include <time.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <signal.h>

   #define maxchild 1

   int inchild=-1;

   void sighandler(int signo){
   char buffer[256];
   int a,b=0;
   switch(signo){
   case SIGUSR1:
       printf("SIGUSR1\n");
       break;
   case SIGUSR2:
       printf("SIGUSR2\n");
       break;
   }
   }


   int main(){
   pid_t ids[maxchild];
   struct sigaction control;
   control.sa_flags=0;
   control.sa_handler=sighandler;
   sigemptyset(&control.sa_mask);
   sigaction(SIGUSR1,&control,NULL);
   sigaction(SIGUSR2,&control,NULL);
   for(int i=0;i<maxchild;i++){
       ids[i]=fork();
       printf("here %d\n",ids[i]);
       if(ids[i]==0){
           printf("in child\n");
           inchild=i+1;
           break;
       }
   }
   while(inchild>=0) {
   }
    //      sleep(1);
   if(inchild==-1){
       for(int i=0;i<maxchild;i++){
           printf("child: %d\n parent: %d\n",ids[i],getpid());
       //  kill(ids[i],SIGUSR1);
       }

   }
     if (inchild==-1) wait(NULL);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   now i want to know the reason of problem.

i want to run the first code and see:
   here (an positive number)
   here 0
   in child
   child: (an positive number)
   parent: (an positive number)
   SIGUSR1 
and the program must continue running until i press the Ctrl+c
(of course the order of line in output doesn't matter)

i didn't want to change the code, i want to know what is the cause of problem.
thank you in advance

Comment: For starters initialise the variables you use properly: Change all `struct sigaction control;` to be `struct sigaction control = {0};`

Comment: Also if you want the parent to live as long as at least one child is alive have it call `wait()` as many times as it forked off a child.

Comment: Undefined behavior for calling non async-safe functions in signal handler.

Comment: @EOF i didn't call any function in signal handler! and in another hand it will be ok if i add just a sleep. so the handler is not the cause of problem.

Comment: @alk i did anything you said but i have same problem yet.

Comment: @milad You're using `printf()`, which isn't on the safe list: http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

Comment: @Shawn thank you very much. it was the problem.

Comment: @EOF thank you. it was exact cause of the problem

Answer (score 1):

If a process has a signal-handler installed this gets called on reception of the signal. This process is not ended then. So all the children are stuck in

```
  while (inchild >= 0) {
  }
```

As no child ends, the parent is blocking in `wait()`.

To fix this replace the above snippet by

```
  if (inchild >= 0) {
    pause();
  }
```

Comment: thank you, but the problem was in signal handler.
i souldn't call printf() in the signal handler

Comment: @milad Just **only** removing the printfs from the signal handler solved you issue? Example 1 without printfs does not block the parent? I doubt this.